# Is RxJava multi-threaded?

Tags: java, rx-java

Let's say I spin off a couple event subscribes, like so:

```
event.subscribe((eventObj) -> {
            // do stuff
        });

event2.subscribe((eventObj) -> {
            // do more stuff
        });
```

Is this implicitly creating two threads?

Comment: I found the following: http://www.grahamlea.com/2014/07/rxjava-threading-examples/, and the answer is "no", RxJava won't create new threads by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of subscription itself does not start computation on another thread, rather the definition of the Observable itself determines the threading behaviour.

As an example

```
Observable
  .just(1, 2, 4)
  .doOnNext(System.out::println)
  .subscribe();
```

will run synchronously.

You can introduce computation on other threads using `subscribeOn` or `observeOn` but be aware that the defaults for some Observable sources and operators mean that they will operate on another thread than the one where subscription occurs. An example is `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` which emits an incrementing integer every second. The default scheduler for this Observable is `Schedulers.computation`. When a subscription happens a thread is chosen from the thread pool associated with `Schedulers.computation` and the emissions occur on that thread. The javadoc for each operator will mention the threading behaviour (probably in terms of `Scheduler`s) so check that if you are unsure.

Answer (score 1):

RX Java is not creating new threads for Subscriptions by default, please check [Scheduler](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html) documentation for introducing multithreading behaviour.